# The array.slice doesn't work, instead of subtracting some values it just copies the array as it is

Tags: javascript, slice

Here is my small script for looking up a word in a text. The problem part is in for loop, when slicing array  doesn't work. The array.slice wants to take values (0,6) and some words of the iterated array are shorter than that, so i guess that might be a problem. Could you give me an advice hot to cope with such a situation?

```
/*jshint multistr:true */
var text = "Etiam accumsan facilisis blandit. Praesent convallis sapien at sagittis ultrices. Proin adipiscing Michal, dolor at adipiscing volutpat, tellus neque adipiscing risus, at interdum magna ante quis risus. Quisque semper in mi imperdiet interdum. Fusce laoreet leo blandit, convallis tellus ut, posuere mauris michal. Quisque eu pulvinar felis. Maecenas ultricies a nulla et dignissim. Praesent egestas quam massa, eget dignissim nulla fringilla nec. Etiam non nulla imperdiet, tempus erat sit amet, luctus nibh. Aenean sit amet elementum nunc. Duis venenatis lacinia rutrum. Fusce vulputate michal lacinia odio, non laoreet metus placerat id. Nam ac risus et nisl pretium vulputate.";
var myName = "michal";
var hits = [];

var name = myName.toLowerCase();
var text2 = text.toLowerCase();

// changes string into array by space
var textWords = text2.split(" ");

// looks for each array value and compares it with the name
for (e = 0;e <= textWords.length; e++) {
    console.log("______ new iteration -> another word to slice _______");

    //  each time 'e' changes, it turns array into another one, consisting of just a word (+ space or comma or dot)
    var g = e+1;
    var textWord = textWords.slice(e, g);
    console.log(textWord);

    // !! PROBLEM part, JS will not slice the former array so it is just name.length long !!
    var potentialName = textWord.slice(0,name.length);
    console.log(potentialName);

    // pushes the result word into empty array 'hits'
    if (potentialName === name) {
        hits.push(potentialName);
//        console.log(hits);
    }
}

// takes the first value of the result array
var nameCopy = hits.slice(0,1);
// counts the number of result values
var count = hits.length;

// checks if ther is any matching value and how many of them there is
if ((nameCopy === name) && (count > 1)) {
    console.log("I've found your name in the text! It's there " + count + " times.");
} else if (nameCopy === name) {
    console.log("I've found your name in the text once.");
} else {
    console.log("Your name is not in the text.");
}
```

Comment: If you're just looking to count matches, why not use `.match()`? `console.log(text.match(/michal/ig).length)`

Comment: Is this just for learning, or you're solving some real world problem? If yes, what is it?

Comment: its just for learning :) i believe there are plenty other and better ways how to do the same thing. but thanks for a tip anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`slice` returns an array, which means that:

- `potentialName` is an array, not a string, and therefore will never be equal (`===`) to `name`.
- `textWord` is also an array, and since `g` is always `e + 1`, we can further infer that it is always an array containing a single element, which the current word. I repeat: `textWord` is an *array* containing the word, not the word itself, as you seem to expect.

Let's run your program step by step starting at the first line of the loop, on the first iteration:

- `e` is 0.
- `g` is `e + 1` which is `0 + 1` which is 1.
- `textWord` is `textWords.slice(e, g)` which is `['etiam', 'accumsan', ...].slice(0, 1)` which is `['etiam']` (an array).
- `potentialName` is `textWord.slice(0, name.length)` which is `['etiam'].slice(0, 6)` which is `['etiam']`.

I guess the third step is not what you want. I guess you want to get the e-th word. What you need to do that is not `slice` but `[]`, like this: `textWords[e]`. Using this, on the first iteration, `textWord` will be `'etiam'` instead of `['etiam']`. Then you can safely compare `textWord` to `name` and see if they are equal using `===`. There is no need for the strings to have the same length.

I hope this will help.

Of course, they are simpler ways of counting words in a text, but I'm guessing this is a learning exercise, so it's fine for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It makes certain things much clearer, but there is still this problem. What if the array textWord is not desired word 'michal', but it is 'michal.' (with dot). How can i subtract the first 6 values, or how can I assign them to the other variable? (in my first code it was supposed to be 'potentialName').

And yes, it is just an learning exercise. I'm sure there are better ways how to achieve the same thing with ease.

Comment: Oh now I see!! Since variable textWord is not an array, but a variable, I can use .substr method to get what I want. Now it works exactly how it's supposed to, i only changed the result line as well in a way you suggested to change textWord[e].

Answer (score 0):

Don´t use name.length, you´ve got to adapt to the length of each word and check matches with the desired length. You could split every word into letters sepparately ("") and check length. name.length´ll always be 6.